# Rails 5 Turbolinks appears to reload page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am still new to Turbolinks and unsure whether it is working correctly. I have a new rails app that I've created with Turbolinks enabled by default. I am using the `link_to` rails helper to build some links. When I click on one of the links the page reloads in the browser. I was under the impression that this should not occur as only the body should be swapped using AJAX. Is there any additional attributes I need to add to my link or additional configuration I need to set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the Turbolinks js loaded in the page. If you are using webpacker and removed the default application js that used the asset pipeline you will probably need to use Turbolinks from npm, import it and then call `Turbolinks.start()` in your entry file.

Comment: I do have Turbolinks in my 'application.js' file: `//= require turbolinks`. I am not currently using webpacker.

Comment: Are your css/js files changing between clicks? Turbolinks will reload if assets have changed or if the link has a data attribute telling it to do so. You can open the JS console to make sure Turbolinks is loaded on the page

Comment: I'm using vendor assets and they do not change from page to page. I do see the Turbolinks js file being loaded on each page. I've pushed the app to Heroku if you have a minute to take a look. The 'Home' and 'About' page are the only two active links: https://stormy-beach-55920.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Do you have any event handlers on those links that could be intercepting the click and modifying the result?

Comment: Thanks for your help CWitty. It was one of the javascript libraries I was using that was somehow breaking turbolinks. The 'animsition' library to be exact. After removing it turbolinks is working again.